# Java - How to close RMI Registry?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm working on a program that uses RMI. The main process starts RMI Registry and a child process, which creates object and binds it into the registry. The biggest problem I am facing is that I can't close RMI Registry properly. I have found out that I could use

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, true);
```

Of course, registry is returned by LocateRegistry.createRegistry function. It makes the registry close its port, but java process that runs the registry is still alive.
So the question is: how to close the RMI Registry with its process? Even when I tried to run

```
registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, true);
```

(what obviously makes no sense), the process still was alive after my program finished.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in 4 seconds from go to whoa, and the JVM exited. You must have had other non-daemon application threads started. You could do all that and then call `System.exit()`. If you find that too violent, make sure all your application threads have exited.